# Access denied connecting to google cloud sql

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to migrate an application from my old server to google's app engine. I want to go with cloud sql as my data has been backed up from mysql.

After going through google's documentation I came up with this configuration for jdoconfig.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<jdoconfig xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig_3_0.xsd">
    <persistence-manager-factory name="cloudsql">

        <property name="javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass" value="org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory" />
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:google:mysql://your-project-id:your-instance-name?user=root" />
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver" />
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalRead" value="true" />
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalWrite" value="false" />
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.RetainValues" value="true" />
        <property name="datanucleus.autoCreateTables" value="true" />
        <property name="datanucleus.transactionIsolation" value="serializable" />
        <property name="datanucleus.cache.level2.type" value="none" />

    </persistence-manager-factory>
</jdoconfig>
```

When I deploy the application to appengine, I get the below exception.

```
javax.jdo.JDOFatalDataStoreException: An SQLException was provoked by the following failure: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
NestedThrowables:
java.sql.SQLException: An SQLException was provoked by the following failure: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:206)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:179)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:136)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:468)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:256)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:235)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have ([as per documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/)) provided access to my appengine instance.

I have also tried changing the connection string. Still no luck!

```
<property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:google:mysql://your-project-id:your-instance-name/dbname?user=root" />
```

I'm using spring's org.springframework.orm.jdo.LocalPersistenceManagerFactoryBean to manage the connections.

Comment: real error is `java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")`. it's not because of cloudsql connection string. seems that this `LocalPersistenceManagerFactoryBean` tries to control Thread, that's not allowed on App Engine. Try with another manager, something simple, single threaded

Comment: Ok. Can you please suggest me an alternative to LocalPersistenceManagerFactoryBean?

Comment: I don't know what `LocalPersistenceManagerFactoryBean` does, so can't say which alternative you can use. As for me I was using plain `SingleConnectionDataSource`, worked fine

Comment: Alright, I'll check it. Thank you!